# reselect: pass multiple parameters to composed selector

Tags: redux, react-redux, reselect

I created a selector that is composed of two other selectors:

```
export const getAvailableFilters = createSelector(
  getOpenedFilterMenu,
  isSaleCategory,
  (filterMenu, isSale) => {
    // .... doing stuff
  },
);
```

The `getOpenedFilterMenu` as well as `isSaleCategory` depend on the redux state and a component prop, but they depend on different props.

When I try to to access the selector like this `getAvailableFilters(state, ownProps.streamId, activeCategory.id)` the TypeScript Compiler throws an error that the type of the first parameter doesn't match.
When I am removing the `isSaleCategory` selector from the input selectors list, TS doesn't complain. Any idea why that is?

How do I compose selectors that have different depending props?

Answer (score 3):

inputSelectors (`getOpenedFilterMenu` and `isSaleCategory`) are called with the same arguments as your `reselect`selector (`state`, `ownProps.streamId`, `activeCategory.id`). It seems that your inputSelectors and the final selector expect different arguments.

A quick solution might consist of wrapping your inputSelectors into and adapter function to feed them with the expected arguments:

```js
export const getAvailableFilters = createSelector(
  (state, streamId, activeCategoryId) => getOpenedFilterMenu(state, activeCategoryId),
  (state, streamId, activeCategoryId) => isSaleCategory(state, streamId),
  (filterMenu, isSale) => {
    // .... doing stuff
  },
);
```